# Need help in converting mandarin to english?

Tags: mandarin, traditional-characters

I am trying to complete my mandarin assignment. can someone please help me to translate these. I was unable to understand them.
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you learning Chinese? Someone is forcing you? Otherwise you might make a little more effort! Try pasting the Chinese into a dictionary! 她姓李， 叫美月。她是台湾老师。Harsh!

Comment: I am curious to know how long you've studied the language. This kind of passage don't seemed to be meant for absolute beginners, especially when there are no Pinyin for some of the more common words. So, if you could answer 3 of the questions, the remaining 2 shouldn't pose any problems? Perhaps you are confused by 臺灣老师, (Taiwanese teacher)? I think you could safely assume that a 臺灣老师 is a 臺灣人。Unless you don't know what 臺灣 means? Maybe you are more familiar with the simplified 台湾?

Comment: @harsh, While we are doing what we can to help language learners, I do not think it is anyone's job to do your homework.

Comment: @WayneCheah Thanks, I am learning Mandarin from 1 month till date. Its compulsory for me to do the course for credits.

Comment: @harsh -- If you don't mind me asking, what institution is this?, as "traditional" characters are used? You may encounter problems later on as generally most material used nowadays is written in "simplified" characters, other then those from Taiwan & Hong Kong. However, in a way, learning the language in its traditional form has some advantages in appreciating the beauty and literary historicity of the Chinese language. In any case, from my experience, it is easier to transit from the traditional to the simplified than the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For questions 1 $ 2, please read the sentences again:

1. 她姓李, 叫美月. 她[是台灣]老師, ..
2. 我姓王, 叫明華, [我是印度人]...

Q: "王先生是哪國人?" - Do not be confused by the title "先生 (Mr.)". The questioner, as the third person, politely refers to 王明華 as Mr. Wong, which is "YOU" in the story. It is not difficult to guess the answer since throughout the short story, there is only one person with the surname "王".

3. There is no correct answer. Though it is correct that 美月喜歡喝奶茶, but 美月 is a woman, so the pronoun referring her should be "她" instead of "他" as shown in all the answers.
4. Your answer is correct.
5. See Q1. (As there is only one person name "美月", you shall quite familiar with her now.)

Please go back to attempt making the correct answers before reading the following:

You shall analyze the full context by pinpoint the primary subjects, and the traits that are attributed to each of them. There are two persons in this short story:

- The first - 王明華, who is representing "you", the student, in this play. He is an Indian, a college student, who likes watching movies and does not like to sign.
- The second, 李美月, is the teacher, who is a Taiwanese (that teaches Chinese, see note below). She likes drinking "milk-tea", and dislikes watching movies.

Now, I think the picture shall be clearer.

Note: While "她是台灣老師" does not provide direct evidence that she is a "Taiwanese", but the answer could be made on the basis of "the best of choices that do not contain mistakes in it". However, it is to be noted that this is a drawback of the Chinese short sentence structure that often creates uncertainties.

Another note is that the traditional Chinese distinguishes the third person pronouns by sex the same as the English, He (他) and she (她).